# Import xls / xlsx / ods: field names are not in first row (just QGIS!)

Tags: qgis, excel

I need to import a xls / xlsx / ods into QGIS. But while the first row (field names) of my XLSX in LibreOffice shows up on the first place as it should, QGIS shows the first row on place 452! As you can see in the screenshot below. I imported the XLSX to QGIS simply by drag'n'drop.

This issue seems to be very strange, because every program I tried, finds the row with field names on the first place! Also saving the XLSX to CSV results in the expected order: first row = field names (second screenshot). I tried saving and copying in all directions and variants - but QGIS still don't finds the field names on row 1.

Limitations:

- I can not go for csv or any other format (just for testing)
- the imported table **need to be editable** in QGIS.
- The plugin "spreadsheet layers" is also not helping, because it uses virtual tables.
- I can't share the data because there is a copyright.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the import-dialogue?

Comment: @erik there is no import dialogue opening ods or xls as a vector layer.

Comment: Then maybe OP should clarify how exactly they import the data.

Comment: @MAP, I made a quick test with an ods file, the single row header was parsed well, I saved the file to xlsx and the header was used from field names in QGIS. Multiline headers are not handled by QGIS.

Comment: Maybe the headers are corrupted, could you try saving as CSV then saving back to XLSX and see if that works (you'll lose your formatting but if you want to edit an xlsx in QGIS you'll probably lose your formatting anyway).

Comment: What kind of characters header row contains ? Dis you specify right encoding ?

Comment: Okay: I did clear all formatting; I saved to csv and back; I changed special characters like ä, ö, ü, ß; and I changed the QGIS language -  no change :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4h of testing and trying! Nothing of the following helped:

1. Changing char set and language,
2. tried several delimiters,
3. reduced word length, delete all formatting and special characters
4. saving from XLSX to CSV and back,
5. import in QGIS as CSV and export it as XLSX

---

**But: Importing the CSV into a Database like SpatiaLite or GPKG and exporting back to XLSX was solving the problem!**

---

Comment: Which qgis version were u referring to ? i'm currently playing with the 3.10 and i had the same problem. I have both libre office and open office installed. my spreasdheet was originally created in **Libre office** with this weird behaviour (ods file) in qgis. Once opened and modified in **Open Office** the problem disappeared. there must be a difference between the two suites ...

Comment: Can't really remember... Must have been QGIS 3.4 or 3.8

Comment: Did u solve this problem ? or ... did u understand the behaviour ? it's still unclear to me ...